# Explain the outputs of Bidirectional LSTM . Output length is 5 , which of them are hidden state and cell state respectively?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, bidirectional

I am trying to use bidirectional LSTM as encoder. I set `return_sequence=True` and `return_state=True` and I am getting an output list with a length of 5.

```
# define model
inputs1 = Input(shape=(3, 1))
lstm1 = Bidirectional(merge_mode = 'ave', layer = LSTM(3, return_sequences=True, return_state = True))(inputs1)
model = Model(inputs=inputs1, outputs=lstm1)
# define input data
data = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]).reshape((1,3,1))
# make and show prediction
pred = model.predict(data)
```

length of the output of Bidirectional lstm is 5

```
len(pred) # 5
```

Shapes of all output from Bidirectional LSTM is

```
for num,i in enumerate(pred):
    print(num, ': ',i.shape)
```

output

```
0 :  (1, 3, 3)
1 :  (1, 3)
2 :  (1, 3)
3 :  (1, 3)
4 :  (1, 3)
```

Since it is bidirectional, I am assuming two of them are hidden states and 2 of them are cell states. Tell me the sequence. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have been searching for the answers and I found it on [this kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/programminghut/seq2seq-chatbot-keras-with-attention#Model)

```
encoder_outputs, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = enc_lstm(enc_embed)
```